# Compare two almost similar xml files and then add tags missing in first xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have to xml files say abc.xml & 123.xml which are almost similar, i mean has the same content, but the second one i.e, 123.xml has more content than the earlier one. I want to read both the files using Java, and compare whether the content present in abc.xml for each tag is same as that in 123.xml, and if 123.xml has some additional tags then add it into abc.xml same as remove tags from 123.xml if abc.xml doesnt have it.

I have two configuration files in xml old and new version. In new one tags could be added or removed and I want to generate xml file using content of old xml file and having xml schema of new xml file. Hope I am bit clear now.

Comment: I can't make sense of this.
123.xml has more tags than abc.xml.
If a tag i missing in abc.xml it should be added to abc.xml and removed from 123.xml?

Comment: I am not perfectly clear what you want to do but I know a very good library which can help you with that. Have a look at XMLUnit http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/

With this you can easily compare two XML documents, generate a Diff object and evaluate different types of differences. Those you can then handle however you want.

Comment: From what you wrote so far it looks like you want to switch file names.

Answer (score 0):

That is a litle bit vague.
There are plenty off ways to do this. Espacialy when you think about how the merge should be done. Is one side always overriding the other one? This would mean also a remove of tags can happen when the newer file has less.

Here are two approaches how to handle this:

1. Use something existing like diff and patch as you can find in any version control system. You could use java to run the diff and patch application on the console.
   In this case you would make a diff. If there is a difference use create patch to get a patch file describing the changes and then apply the patch.
2. If you wil do everything in java, i would not try to parse the file and work serialized on it. It will drive you crazy. I would use a kind of marshalling like JAX-B to convert the xml in a Pojo. Then you can compare the pojos and add or remove missing elements from the target pojo and then serialize it back to xml.

Hope this will get you a starting point for your further investigation ;)

Comment: Thanx. But I want to do it on android device. I know how to validate xml file against xml file. But It does not give me proper result which tags are added and which are removed. Is it possible validation give me result which tags should be added or removed?

Comment: I would not try to do it on xml layer, deserialize your xml in to representation of pojos which you can easly compare and serialize in xml again. This is also possible on android. I figured out that there is no JAX-B on Android, but look here it should help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/